# Navigation arrow over image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add navigation (Left - Right) arrows on the center of image.
But somehow I don't have images of fixed sizes. They can be of any height and width.

Here is what I tried http://jsfiddle.net/vh1fp0k0/

```css
 #case-example-cover {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 #nav-container {
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
 #nav-container div {
   position: absolute;
   top: -webkit-calc(50% - 19px);
   top: -moz-calc(50% - 19px);
   top: -ms-calc(50% - 19px);
   top: calc(50% - 19px);
   width: 38px;
   height: 38px;
   background-image: url("http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/lhmdzrfd.png");
   border: 1px solid blue;
 }
 #case-left {
   left: 0;
 }
 #case-right {
   right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="case-example-cover">
  <div id="nav-container">
    <div id="case-left"></div>
    <div id="case-right"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x299" />
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div id="case-example-cover">
  <div id="nav-container">
    <div id="case-left"></div>
    <div id="case-right"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired result

[image: Desired Result]

How to do achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean you do not have an image?

Comment: @Ala Typo **I don't have image of fixed size** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the `#case-example-cover` div `inline-block` it shrink wraps to the image size.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vh1fp0k0/3/)

```css
 #case-example-cover {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 #nav-container {
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
 #nav-container img {
   display: block;
 }
 #nav-container div {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   width: 38px;
   height: 38px;
   background-image: url("http://s7.directupload.net/images/140625/lhmdzrfd.png");
   border: 1px solid blue;
 }
 #case-left {
   left: 0;
 }
 #case-right {
   right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="case-example-cover">
  <div id="nav-container">
    <div id="case-left"></div>
    <div id="case-right"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x299" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="case-example-cover">
  <div id="nav-container">
    <div id="case-left"></div>
    <div id="case-right"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Paulie_D this is working fine, but after doing this i'm not able alight image to the center of the page. Using `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` . Will be great if you can help.

Comment: Awesome, many many thanks. This just save my day. Sorry for not mentioning that :)